Issue with \vspace{\stretch{1}} not working inside mdframed environment
I'm encountering a problem with using \vspace{\stretch{1}} inside the mdframed environment. I'm trying to add some vertical space after a theorem inside the frame, but it seems that the \vspace{\stretch{1}} command is not functioning as expected.
I know I can use \vspace{x cm} but I don't want to use that. I want to divide the page evenly.
I have
Here's a minimal example of what I have:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[
    linecolor=blue,
    linewidth=2pt,
    backgroundcolor=orange!20,
]
\begin{theorem}
  Some subtheorem.
\end{theorem}
\vspace{\stretch{1}}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}


mdrframed will fit a box to its contents. Move the stretch  outside of the mdframed environment

This is the same problem that use x\par\vfill x  in a minipage or a \parbox. Will not work with:
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{3cm} x\par\vfill x \end{minipage}} 

Because, OK, you want to fill the box, ... but how far? The box have not a predefined height.
It work in the main text because the page have a forced height. It stretches only if you stretch it to something. In a minipage, you can do that  fixing the height of the box:
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[c][3cm][c]{3cm} x\par\vfill x \end{minipage}} 


Note that if you use a tcolorbox instead of mdframed, that allow the option of fix the height, even this will not work:
\begin{tcolorbox}[height=3cm]  x\par  \vfill x \end{tcolorbox}

(It's not a bug, it's a feature!)

I want to divide the page evenly

If you want equal boxes then you can use the raster library of tcolorbox, so the height of every box is fixed by the box with more height:

\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[raster]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=1, size=small, title={\sffamily\bfseries Free  height box No. \thetcbrasternum}]
\begin{tcolorbox}First box\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}Second box\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}This is a box\\with a second line \\ with a third line \\ with a fourth line  \end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}Another box\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}A box\par \vspace{.3 cm} again\end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcbraster}

\newpage

\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=1, size=small, raster equal height,
size=small,colframe=red!50!black,colback=red!10!white,colbacktitle=red!50!white,coltitle=black,
title={\sffamily\bfseries Evenlized box No. \thetcbrasternum}]
\begin{tcolorbox}First box\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}Second box\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}This is a box\\with a second line \\ with a third line \\ with a fourth line  \end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}Another box\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}A box\par \vspace{.3 cm} again\end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcbraster}
\end{document}

